# Why elements defiend with id available in console by same name?

Tags: javascript

If you define an element with `id` attribute on it

```
<p id="text">some text</p>
```

then you will be able to access this element in the console by value provided in the `id` attribute.

```
>> text
```

For example, if open devtools on this page and type `search` to the console, then the form element will be logged.

Does anyone know where this functionality described?

Comment: [Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables) ?

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot.